# Share Fortran 90 module data with F2PY between many extension modules

Tags: python, fortran, shared-libraries, f2py

I want to share data which is located in a Fortran 90 module between many self compiled F2PY extension modules. The documentation of F2PY says that this is not possible due to to how Python imports shared libraries in general.

> F2PY generates wrappers to common blocks defined in a routine
> signature block. Common blocks are visible by all Fortran codes linked
> with the current extension module, but not to other extension modules
> (this restriction is due to how Python imports shared libraries).
>
> [...]
>
> The F2PY interface to Fortran 90 module data is similar to Fortran 77
> common blocks.

[Link to Documentation](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/%7Efrancois.denis/IAAM1/numpy-html-1.14.0/f2py/python-usage.html#common-blocks)

Due to the fact, that I have to use about 100 nested Fortran 90 subroutines, I need to share data between them. Any suggestions how I can achieve that?

I thought about passing every variable as parameter to each subroutine and return the variables afterwards, but this sounds somehow wrong.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. More people will see your question.

Comment: The thing you cite is about common blocks, not about modules. Modules work just fine. There is no place for common blocks in modern code.

Comment: Thank your for the hint about the tag. 
Unfortunately F2PY handles modules in the same way as common blocks as the documentation says. So I dont think it will work out, because for the different extension modules are still different shared libraries for Python or not?

Comment: If you compile them as one library, they are one library. It is really up to you how you do that.

Comment: I am not able to compile them in one library. I need them seperate and to share variables.

Comment: In that case you should probabky some details including an example simplified code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though just a trial-and-error approach, how about putting the variable module and all the subroutines into a single file and compile it with f2py (*1)? For example...

mytest.f90:

```
include "vars.f90"
include "sub1.f90"
include "sub2.f90"
```

vars.f90:

```
module vars
    integer :: n = 100
end
```

sub1.f90:

```
subroutine sub1
    use vars, only: n
    implicit none
    print *, "sub1: n = ", n
end
```

sub2.f90:

```
subroutine sub2
    use vars, only: n
    implicit none
    print *, "sub2: n = ", n
    print *, "adding 1 to n"
    n = n + 1
    print *, "n = ", n
end
```

Compile:

```
f2py -c -m mytest mytest.f90
```

Test:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3
>>> import mytest
>>> mytest.vars.n
array(100, dtype=int32)
>>> mytest.sub1()
 sub1: n =          100
>>> mytest.sub2()
 sub2: n =          100
 adding 1 to n
 n =          101
>>> mytest.sub2()
 sub2: n =          101
 adding 1 to n
 n =          102
>>> mytest.vars.n = 777
>>> mytest.sub2()
 sub2: n =          777
 adding 1 to n
 n =          778
```

(*1) In the above case, simply giving all the file names to f2py seems sufficient, for example,

```
$ f2py -c -m mytest vars.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to have them in one file. Compile them into one .so file should be fine. But the OP, for some strange reason, says it is not possible.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the info, I've just tried it and it seems to work (for the test above). Then OP might try something like "f2py -c -m mytest vars.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90 ... sub100.f90" (or with wild card for sub*.f90)

Comment: @roygvib : Thank you very much for the explanation and example! Now I got the clue/hint Vladimir F suggested. Vladimir F, thank you too for your help. I really appreciate it.
I still have one question, is there a relevant difference between `$ f2py -c -m mytest vars.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90` and `f2py -c -m mytest mytest.f90` ? It looks like there is no difference because mytest.f90 contains vars.f90 + sub1.f90 + sub2.f90.

Comment: @Christopher49124 As far as I tested with the above example, there was no difference. But, I'm afraid that there may appear differences when some f2py-specific "directives" are used (for telling f2py about the argument intent etc). Overall, I guess it will be better to pass all the file names explicitly to the f2py command (like f2py -c -m mytest vars.f90 sub1.f90....). We may also be able to use bash etc to pass a lot of file names conveniently (rather than including them into a file).